# Finding limits $l=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a} $ & $m= \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a} $.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$l=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a} $$&$$m= \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a} $$ where $a>0$. If $l=m$ then find the value of $'a'$.
I get $$l=a^alna  $$ $$m= a^alna-a^a $$  Certainly not correct as $a>0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint for the first:**
Writing $h=x-a\to 0$, you can rewrite
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a} &= \frac{e^{x\ln x}-e^{x\ln a}}{x-a}
= \frac{e^{(a+h)\ln (a+h)}-e^{(a+h)\ln a}}{h}
\end{align}$$
After doing this change towards $h\to 0$, if you are allowed to use Taylor series I would advocate (for both limits) to use Taylor expansions. The limits will then come quite easily. For instance, here is a derivation:

> $$\begin{align}\frac{e^{(a+h)\ln (a+h)}-e^{(a+h)\ln a}}{h} &=\frac{e^{a(\ln a + \ln(1+\frac{h}{a})) + h(\ln a + \ln(1+\frac{h}{a})}-e^{a\ln a}e^{h\ln a}}{h} \\&=\frac{e^{a\ln a + a\cdot\frac{h}{a} + o(h) + h\ln a}-e^{a\ln a}e^{h\ln a}}{h}  \\&= e^{a\ln a}\frac{e^{ h + \ln a  + o(h)}-e^{h\ln a}}{h} \\&= e^{a\ln a}\frac{1+ h(1+\ln a) + o(h)- 1 - h\ln a}{h} \\&= e^{a\ln a}\frac{h + o(h)}{h} = e^{a\ln a}(1+o(1))\end{align}$$

(place your mouse over the grey area to show the contents)

---

**For the second:**
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a} &=
\frac{e^{x\ln a}-e^{a\ln x}}{x-a} = \frac{e^{a\ln a+h\ln a}-e^{a\ln a + a\ln(1+\frac{h}{a})}}{h} \\
&=e^{a\ln a}\frac{e^{h\ln a}-e^{a(\frac{h}{a} + o(h))}}{h}
= e^{a\ln a}\frac{e^{h\ln a}-e^{h + o(h)}}{h}\\
&= e^{a\ln a}\frac{1+h\ln a +o(h)-(1+h +o(h))}{h}\\
&= e^{a\ln a}\frac{h(\ln a - 1) +o(h)}{h} \\
&= e^{a\ln a}\left(\ln a - 1 + o(1)\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Last part:
If $m=\ell$, then $$e^{a\ln a}(\ln a -1) = e^{a\ln a}$$
Simplifying by $e^{a\ln a}$ and resolving the remaining equation will give you $a$.

Comment: I am getting $l=a^alna$ .

Comment: @arutoregni Edited -- hopefully, the typo/mistakes are gone now.

Comment: @arutoregni See edited post (I added the Taylor expansion-based derivations for both limits).

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the first limit: I suppose that $a>0$. Put $g(x)=x^x=\exp(x\log x)$, and $h(x)=a^x$. Your expression is $\displaystyle \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}-\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: (solving the first one):

$$l=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^x-a^x\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-a\right)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^x(1+\ln(x))-a^x\ln(a)}{1}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}\left(x^x(1+\ln(x))-a^x\ln(a)\right)=a^a(1+\ln(a))-a^a\ln(a)=a^a$$