# Compute a limit without L'Hopital's rule $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would want to know how we can compute the following limit by using only fundamental limits.

$$\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{a^x-x^a}{x-a},$$ where $a$ is a positive real number.

My idea was to use a substitution: $y=x-a$. We get
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \dfrac{a^aa^y-(y+a)^a}{y}
=a^a\left[ \lim\limits_{y \to 0} \dfrac{a^y-1+1-(\frac{y+a}{a})^a}{y} \right]
=a^a\left[ \ln a+\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{1-(\frac{y+a}{a})^a}{y} \right].
$$

I am looking forward to read any tips on how I can continue from this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the result should be $$a^a(\log(a)-1)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. Sorry, but how can this help solving OP's problem? We can always check the correctness of the result using LH rule.

Comment: but to know the result helps

Comment: Related: [Finding limits $l=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a} $ & $m= \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a} $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1578336). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20a%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7Ba%5Ex-x%5Ea%7D%7Bx-a%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding limits $l=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{x^x-a^x}{x-a} $ & $m= \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{a^x-x^a}{x-a} $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578336/finding-limits-l-lim-x-rightarrow-a-fracxx-axx-a-m-lim-x-rig)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint: to conclude you shall use the limit
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^a - 1}{x} = a $$
can you figure out how?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I completely forgot this result.

Answer (score 13):

$$\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{a^x-x^a}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{a^x+a^a-a^a-x^a}{x-a}$$$$=\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{a^x-a^a}{x-a}-\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{x^a-a^a}{x-a}=f'(a)-g'(a)$$

where $f(x)=a^x$ and $g(x)=x^a$

Comment: No L'Hopital means no derivatives.

Comment: @ThePirateBay...No L'Hospital means no L'Hospital not no derivatives...;) ..Also it is not stated in the question that we must not use the definition of the derivative...

Comment: I contend that this answer doesn’t invoke LH’s rule, because it makes no mention of the conditions required to apply the rule. Therefore, there’s no way that this could be a reformulation of the theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Your steps are good, now just apply well-known limit
$$ \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{(n+1)^k - 1}{n} = k $$
Your last limit becomes
$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{(ya^{-1}+1)^a-1}{y}=aa^{-1}=1$$
Substituting it in your original expression
$$a^a(\ln a+(-1))=a^a(\ln a-1)$$